# Show $\frac 1 {P(z)}$ is continuous, where $P(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0$ is a polynomial with $a_i \in \mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $$P(z) = a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0$$ is a polynomial with $a_i \in \mathbb C$.

I know $P(z)$ must be continuous, since it is a sum of continuous functions which are in turn products of continuous function and hence continuous.

However, how do I show $$\frac 1 {P(z)}$$

is continuous at $z_0 \in \mathbb C, P(z_0) \neq 0$ ?

Let $\epsilon >0$.

I must show $|\frac 1 {P(z)} - \frac 1 {P(z_0)}| < \epsilon$ for $|z - z_0|< \delta$, where I'd no luck in finding such a $\delta > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the fact that $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $C^*$, $P$ is on $D$ and since $P(D) \subset C^*$ so is $z \in D \rightarrow \frac{1}{P(z)}$ by composition where $D=\{z$ $|$ $P(z) \neq 0\}$ is an open subset of $C$.

If you really want to prove it by hand, you can say that $|\frac{1}{P(z_1)} - \frac{1}{P(z_2)}| = |\frac{P(z_2) - P(z_1)}{P(z_1)P(z_2)}|$ and you see that it goes to zero when $z_1$ goes to $z_2$ (since $|P(z_1)P(z_2)|$ goes to $|P(z_2)|^2 \neq 0$ and $|P(z_1) - P(z_2)| \to 0$ by continuity of $P$). Using the basical definition with $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ seems not to be a good idea here, since you go through an inversion and a product and to find the exact formula for $\delta$ can be quite tricky.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification @YannHamdaui